# how to search keyword in database field if keyword is appearing in different places of string?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field in database where i want to make a keyword search. But i have a problem in writing a Mysql query i think.

```
"select * from products as P where P.product_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$search."[[:>:]]'";
```

I have used the REGEXP to get the exact keyword in search.The code is running properly.But the problem i have is when

suppose i want to search "washing machine". But i entered "washingmachine".

Then the value of $search will be

```
$search="washingmachine";
```

And the keyword in table's product_name field appears like

```
product_id | product_name
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          | Haier 6.2 Kg Ruby Red Semi Automatic Top Load Washing Machine  XPB 62-0613RU
2          | Haier (6.2 Kg,Aqua Blue) Semi-automatic Top-loading Washing Machine XPB62-0613AQ
3          | Haier (6.5 Kg, ) Semi-automatic Top-loading Washing Machine  XPB 65-114D
```

I have also used LIKE clause but have the same problem.

How i search this. If there is any solution please share.

Comment: You have to enter what you want to search for, Entering something else means you are searching for somethig else. Thats just obvious

Comment: Use RLIKE rather than REGEXP .

Comment: I can enter what i want to search But if i think as a user i will not enter keyword  in correct manner. thanks for reply.@RiggsFolly

Comment: @MubasharIqbal according to mysql reference RLIKE is just a synonym for REGEXP

Comment: ahan, thank you @DelPedro

Comment: But that is my point! You can only search for what is entered. If I enter `red` in a search but I ment to enter `orange` how can you possibly spot my mistake. The search runs on what the user enters, not on what the user may have intended to enter, or what YOU think the user may have ment to enter.

Comment: However, you might like to look at using `SOUNDEX()`

Comment: It is used to evaluate the similarity of two strings. How can i use it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use *MATCH()...AGAINST()* as mentioned here: ["Natural Language Full-Text Searches"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

Comment: Same problem. Didn't work.  SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE MATCH (
product_name
)
AGAINST (
'washingmachine'
IN NATURAL LANGUAGE
MODE
)  this query i have used.